# Update statement inside fetch_assoc()

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

I'm am a DBA serving as my own developer for the time being. I'm writing a PHP template for some automated emails on a training system that will goose inactive students on a periodic basis. I'm having an issue, I think, with my WHERE statement in the update to affect only the current record. I can update all records by removing the WHERE statement, but none with it.

Can anyone see the my error? My main query and my mail function work fine.

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect('localhost','xxx','xxx','xxx');

$result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT email1 FROM email_test WHERE last_login < (NOW() - INTERVAL 45 DAY) AND email_number=0');

if($result->num_rows >= 1){
$subject = "A test of the email CRON";
$message='It has been 45 days since your last login.';

while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {

$email="{$row['email1']}"; 

mysqli_query($link, 'UPDATE email_test SET email_number = 1, email_sent = NOW() WHERE email1=$email');

mail($email, $subject, $message); }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quotes need fixing in:

```
mysqli_query($link, 'UPDATE email_test SET email_number = 1, email_sent = NOW() WHERE email1=$email');
```

Should be changed to:

```
mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE email_test SET email_number = 1, email_sent = NOW() WHERE email1='$email'");
```

In php variables are parsed in double quotes while variables are not parsed in single quotes.

Comment: Thank You! I couldn't see the forest for the trees.

Comment: on a related note: I plan to use 3 of these statements to notify students on various criteria and call them in a CRON. Can I put all 3 `<?php  ?>` calls in the same text file and call it once, or do i need 3 separate files and call them individually. They will all query the same tables.

Comment: You can put all 3 in the same text file if you want.  You can also break them out if you want to ;)

Answer (score 0):

if email1 is a string then it must be in quotes

```
mysqli_query($link, 'UPDATE email_test SET email_number = 1, email_sent = NOW() WHERE email1="' . $email .'"');
```